# Как переделать код, чтобы js сработал не по клику, а при загрузке

Tags: php, javascript

Приветствую всех знатоков! Помогите пожалуйста решением задачи! :) 
Есть такой вот код:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

        /*
         * Smart Notifications
         */
        $('#eg1').click(function(e) {

            $.bigBox({
                title : "Ошибка!",
                content : "Это сообщение об ошибке и оно исчезнет через 9 секунд!",
                color : "#C46A69",
                icon : "fa fa-warning shake animated",
                number : "1",
                timeout : 9000
            });

            e.preventDefault();

        }); })
```

Но в данном виде он срабатывает лишь когда происходит клик по элементу с id eg1, как мне переделать данный код, чтобы он срабатывал при выводе на страницу через

```
<?php echo "ДАННЫЙ КОД"; ?>
```

Заранее всех БЛАГОДАРЮ!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  function ShowBigBox() {
    $.bigBox({
      title : "Ошибка!",
      content : "Это сообщение об ошибке и оно исчезнет через 9 секунд!",
      color : "#C46A69",
      icon : "fa fa-warning shake animated",
      number : "1",
      timeout : 9000
    });
  }

  /*
   * Smart Notifications
   */
  $('#eg1').click(function(e) {
    ShowBigBox();
    e.preventDefault();
  }); 

  ShowBigBox();
});
```

Comment: БЛАГОДАРЮ!!! ВСЁ РАБОТАЕТ КАК НУЖНО :)